# python postgresql module install on MAC OS is failing

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pip

i am trying to install `psycopg2-binary` module on my Mac OS. install is failing with below error message.

Any help to resolve this error?

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /private/var/folders/1s/xllnfc3n1j988pnws9g93tfm77pffn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-7b1acytt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info
      writing /private/var/folders/1s/xllnfc3n1j988pnws9g93tfm77pffn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-7b1acytt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/1s/xllnfc3n1j988pnws9g93tfm77pffn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-7b1acytt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/1s/xllnfc3n1j988pnws9g93tfm77pffn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-7b1acytt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/1s/xllnfc3n1j988pnws9g93tfm77pffn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-7b1acytt/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: Would you like to share more info about your Python version and how you install psy-copg2-binary?

Comment: @Joe_Bao I was using `Python 3.8.9` version

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may be related to your question, and it seems that a is also provided there. https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1286

You may also try to build psycopg2 from source following the instruction. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#prerequisites